# Função strftime() %A está retornando dia da semana sem -feira

Tags: php, data

Estou executando a função `srtftime()` com o parâmetro `%A`, porém as datas estão retornando sem o "-feira", somente segunda, terça, quarta, etc.

Alguém já teve este problema?

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'pt_BR', 'Portuguese_Brazil');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

echo strftime('%A, %d de %B de %Y', strtotime('today'));
```

Comment: Fiz um teste com esse código e retornou `quinta-feira, 06 de julho de 2017` tem como jogar ele no ideone ou outro interpretador online de php para tirar a dúvida?

Comment: idone retorna sempre em ingles.

Comment: Aqui também funcionou bem. Está a testar onde? local ou online?

Comment: Estou executando no meu servidor web de produção PHP 5.3.3